# javafx tableview columview con boton necesito que al hacer click auto seleccione la fila

Tags: java, javafx

Necesito que al hacer click en el botón que ya está en una columna se seleccione automáticamente la fila para poder hacer `get` y `set` al item selecionado. De lo contrario, genera `nullpointer`.
Estuve pensando en agregar un listener que cuando hago click en el boton selecione el *row* directamente, pero no se.

*Esta es una captura de pantalla :*

[image: Captura de pantalla.]

Este es el código:

```
botonVisitar.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {

    TextInputDialog dialog1 = new TextInputDialog();
    Stage stage1 = (Stage) dialog1.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
    stage1.getIcons().add(new Image(this.getClass().getResource("icono.jpg").toString()));
    dialog1.setTitle("Visita:");
    dialog1.setContentText("Ingresar Tipo de visita: (por ejemplo: llamada, mail, mensaje, etc)");
    Optional<String> result1 = dialog1.showAndWait();
    if (result1.isPresent()) {

        TablaVisita.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().setTipoVisita(result1.get());
        TablaVisita.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().setFechaVisita(LocalDate.now());

        //si no esta selecionado me dice nullPointer. 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

encontre la solución en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43010611/javafx-tableview-columview-with-button-i-need-to-click-button-autoselect-row
, la posteo para que sepa la resolución el que esta en apuros:

```
    botonVisitar.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {

        ...

        if (result1.isPresent()) {
            MyItem item = (MyItem) getTableRow().getItem();

            item.setTipoVisita(result1.get());
            item.setFechaVisita(LocalDate.now());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo haces como lo tenes, llamas en el onaction del boton.

el get es facil:

```html
Visita miVisita;

botonVisitar.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
  try{
    mivisita=TablaVisita.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
  }
  catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println("no se ha seleccionado una visita");
  }

}
```

en este caso no deberias llegar nunca al catch, ya que todos los valores los cargas de algun lado.

Comment: pero de esta manera también me va a hacer nullpointer si no selecciono previamente la fila. lo que yo quiero hacer es en ese onAction que cuando haga click automáticamente me seleccione la fila donde esta ubicado el button. es posible eso?